# In Bash on Ubuntu 14.04, Unity, How can I get the total size of an open window including borders and title?

Tags: bash, window, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-unity

I have used the answer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14159/how-do-i-find-the-window-dimensions-and-position-accurately-including-decoration in my bash scripts, and had good success with my [Silentcast](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast/#silentcast) application on Xfce, but now that others are using it, they are finding some problems in Ubuntu 14.04, Unity. Here is one problem caused by the output of:

`xwininfo -id $(xdotool getactivewindow)`

Showing:

`Relative upper-left X:  0
Relative upper-left Y:  0`

Which I use to calculate the width of the borders and the height of the titlebar. They should not be 0.

Does anyone know how to get the width of the window borders and the height of the titlebar in Unity for Ubuntu 14.04.

Or, how to directly get the full window dimensions?

I have filed a bug against xorg for the xwininfo package https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=84348

I have also found out information about creating your own theme in Unity under Ubuntu 14.04: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming

It seems like the answer is in that theming page somewhere, but I don't understand it yet especially since I don't use Ubuntu or Unity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This applies also to compiz. There are a couple of ways you can get these informations in some ways:

```
wnckprop --xid=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
```

Otherwise, you can just mix the Absolute value you get from xwininfo together with the size of the decorations that are accessible using:

```
xprop _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS --xid=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
```

As you can read in the [freedesktop documentation](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html#idm140238712267120), that property lists the sizes in this order: left, right, top, bottom.

For your information, if you want to get the full frame size, including the input area around the window, you can use `xwininfo -frame`.

Comment: Fantastic. I like mixing xprop _NET_FR... with xwininfo -frame because wnckprop is part of a package that's too big. I would like to be sure the output of xprop ... is giving me the widths in the following order: left, right, top, bottom. The "top" is obvious because it's large, but the rest are all the same number on everything I've tested. I want to cover any strange theme out there though and would need to be sure that order is correct.

Comment: Trevino has answered me on [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/unity/+question/255025). Yes, it is left, right, top, bottom, and here is the documentation: http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html#idm140238712267120

Comment: After experimentation, I understand better what the input area refers to in Ubuntu. Since the border default size is 0, there's a 10px area around the window where you can grab the window for resizing. It may have other purposes too. But, it seems to be an invisible 10px border. So, Absolute from xwininfo gives the interior window while xwininfo -frame gives the entire window including title-bar and an additional 10px all around (if the input area is 10px). The xprop... gives just the size of the decorations, not including the input area. So all 3 commands are needed to get a full picture.